# Issue with Android Support Design FloatingActionButton shape

Tags: android, android-support-design

I tried to used `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` with this XML.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/FAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

On API 22 it looks great, but shadow is missing

[image]

But on API 16 it is acting weird

[image]

Am I using this control correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's turns out that this is a bug in Android Support Design in API 16.

[More about it](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175067)

> Workaround for now is to set app:borderWidth="0dp"